# How to find all no repeat combinations form specific single arrays use Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, combinations

I am a Javascript beginner, I have a personal project to use program to find all the possible & no repeat combinations form specific arrays

I suppose have 3 sets of products and 10 style in each set, like this array

[1,2,3,4..10,1,2,4...8,9,10]

```
①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩
①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩
①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩
```

totaly array length = 30

I plan to randomly separate it into 5 children, but they can't repeat the same products style

OK result:
①②③④⑤⑥ ✔
②③④⑤⑥⑦ ✔
①②③⑧⑨⑩ ✔
④⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩ ✔
①⑤⑦⑧⑨⑩ ✔

Everyone can evenly assign products that are not duplicated

NG:
①②③④⑤⑥ ✔
①②③④⑤⑦ ✔
①②⑥⑧⑨⑩ ✔
③④⑤⑦⑧⑨ ✔
⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑩ ✘ (because number 10 repeated)

---

My solution is randomly to assign 5 sets of arrays, then use "new Set(myArray[i]).size;" check the value sum is 30 or not, Use [do..white], while sum is not 30 then repeat to do the random assign function until the result is not duplicated.

like this:

```
function splitArray() {
  
    do {
      var productArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];  //Just for sample, actualy this array will be more then 30
      var productPerChildArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        GroupNum = [];
  
        for (var v = 0; v < 6; v++) {
          var selectNum = productArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * productArray.length)];
          GroupNum.push(selectNum);
          productArray = removeItemOnce(productArray, selectNum);
        }
  
        productPerChildArray.push(GroupNum);
      }
    } while (checkIfArrayIsUnique(productPerChildArray));
  
    return productPerChildArray;
  }
  
  //---------check repeat or not----------
  function checkIfArrayIsUnique(myArray) {
    var countRight  = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      countRight += new Set(myArray[i]).size;
    }
    return (countRight != 5*6);
  }

  //----------update productArray status----------
function removeItemOnce(arr, value) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
      arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return arr;
  }

  console.log(splitArray());
```

Seems to solve the problem, but actualy productArray is not must 30, this solution will spend to much time to try the no repeat combination. Low efficiency

I believe they have a other solution to solve the problem better than my idea

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be: just place the next number in an `array` that is selected randomly - of course, filter out those that already contain the next number.

```js
// the beginning dataset
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

// the size of the groups to be formed (must divide the
// size of beginning dataset without a remainder)
const ARR_LENGTH = 6

// creating the array that will be filled randomly
const getBaseArray = ({ data, arrLength }) => {
  const num = parseInt(data.length / arrLength, 10)
  return Array.from(Array(num), () => [])
}

// filter arrays that satisfy conditions
const conditions = ({ subArr, val }) => {
  if (subArr.includes(val)) return false
  if (ARR_LENGTH <= subArr.length) return false
  return true
}
const getArraysFiltered = ({ val, arr }) => {
  return arr
    .map((e, i) => ({
      origIdx: i,
      subArr: e,
    }))
    .filter(({ subArr }) => conditions({ subArr, val }))
}

// select a random array from a list of arrays
const getRandomArrIdx = ({ arr }) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
}

// get the original array index from the filtered values
const getArrIdx = ({ val, arr }) => {
  const filtered = getArraysFiltered({ val, arr })
  if (!filtered.length) return -1

  const randomArrIdx = getRandomArrIdx({ arr: filtered })
  return filtered[randomArrIdx].origIdx
}

const getFinalArr = ({ data }) => {
  // short circuit: if the data cannot be placed in
  // arrays evenly, then it's a mistake (based on
  // the current ruleset)
  if (data.length % ARR_LENGTH) return [false]

  // creating the array that will hold the numbers
  const arr = getBaseArray({ data, arrLength: ARR_LENGTH })
 
  let i = 0;
  for (i; i < data.length; i++) {
    const idx = getArrIdx({
      val: data[i],
      arr,
    })
    // if there's no place that the next number could be
    // placed, then break (prematurely), so the algorithm
    // can be restarted as early as possible
    if (idx === -1) break;
    arr[idx].push(data[i])
  }

  if (i < data.length) {
    // restart algorithm if we couldn't place
    // all the numbers in the dataset
    return getFinalArr({ data })
  } else {
    return arr
  }

}

// constructing the final array of arrays & logging them:
console.log('res', getFinalArr({ data }).join(' '))
console.log('res', getFinalArr({ data }).join(' '))
console.log('res', getFinalArr({ data }).join(' '))
console.log('res', getFinalArr({ data }).join(' '))
```

I don't know if it's more efficient, but I found this question interesting.

Now, the algorithm is

- broken down into small logical steps that are
- easy to follow
- simple to tweak to needs
- works with all sizes of data (if the groups to be made can be filled equally)

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect~ I still learning a Javascript. so I will try to understand the theory.